# Laravel aws only the first page works

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, apache2

I deployed my laravel 8 app to aws ec2 instance but it is only the first page that is working

.htaccess file and index.php file is in the root directory

.htaccess file

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Send Requests To Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

site-available/laraqueue.conf

```
 <virtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin support@ahtcloud.com
    ServerName http://18.189.174.42
    ServerAlias http://18.189.174.42
    DocumentRoot /var/www/laraqueue/public

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/laraqueue/public>
        Require all granted
        AllowOverride All
        Options Indexes Multiviews FollowSymLinks
    </Directory>
</virtualHost>
```

Comment: When you say only first page is working what happens if you try to visit other pages? Also "server name" should not include the protocol and it looks like the way you defined it might conflict with the apache default site

Comment: @apokryfos it says unable to connect. Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at 18.189.174.42. The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy.

Answer (score 0):

Run `sudo a2enmod rewrite`

Update you conf file like below code

```
<Directory /var/www/laraqueue/public>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

Restart the apache server.

```
service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it did not work for me

Comment: @oshabz I've updated conf file code as i used in one project. try on it once.